# Is there a specific or standard definition for what classes as a peak?

Tags: classification, definition

I am working on some peak analysis at present, essentially just a programme that will identify peaks in a histogram and return the graph with those peaks pointed out.

My question is, is there a standard definition of what is classed as a peak, as in a percentage above the background the height ought to be, or perhaps a relation with the FWHM of some sort?

Comment: What is the objective of this analysis?  That is, what conclusions, decisions, or actions will you draw as a result of identifying peaks?  How are the histogram bins determined?

Comment: It is to determine whether electronics are functioning as they are supposed to, there is one histogram bin per channel, there should only be one peak, if there is more than one then the electronics will need investigated

Comment: Typically one does't use histograms directly for this: a theoretical model, such a Gaussian or Poisson (or whatever physical theory suggests is appropriate) is fit to the peak.  The presence of more than one peak can be detected by fitting a mixture model or testing the goodness of fit or through a library search, depending on what this spectrum is representing.